# How can I write this in function component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    signedIn: false,
    name: "",
    photoUrl: ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out you are saying functional component not class component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) with default values.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const Component = (props) => {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [photoUrl, setPhotoUrl] = useState("");

  return <></>
}

export { Component };
```

Comment: signIn = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId:
          "833456763323-ig9ndr0tbvb62jv4ddn6j8pos3a49m35.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        //iosClientId: YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE,  <-- if you use iOS
        scopes: ["profile", "email"]
      })